# Laravel redirect to optional page aftet logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

in laravel as we know we can change

`protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login';`

to redirect login after logout, but i have some pages and i would like to redirect to them for example redirect to `pages/aboutUs` or `pages/contactUs` or `pages/home` optionally and i cant change `$redirectAfterLogout` variable to them

how can i implementing this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

`protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login';`

but remember, that the action in controller that you redirect to, can not have in `__constructor`:

`$this->middleware('auth');`

Check also if your `web middleware` does not require form user to be logged in.

Then redirection will work.

Good Luck!